# Search from model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

My view.py is like this

```
def searchnews(request):
    name = request.GET.get('name', 'default')
    categry = request.GET.get('category', 'default')
    NewTable.objects.filter(headline__contains=name).filter(category=categry)
```

What I want is that when the value of any element in querystring is empty
like 
if category="" I want to get all the category result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of an ability to [chain filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters) in Django.

Set the default to an empty string in case it is not found in `request.GET`. Check for not emptiness before adding an additional `filter()`:

```
category = request.GET.get('category', '')
results = NewTable.objects.filter(headline__contains=name)
if category:
    results = results.filter(category=category)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to build the filter as a kwargs dictionary

```
kwargs = {'headline__contains': name}
if 'category' in request.GET and request.GET['cateogry'] is not '':
    kwargs['category': request.GET['category']
queryset = NewTable.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a condition to apply the `filter` only if a category is provided:

```
categry = request.GET.get('category', '')
queryset = NewTable.objects.filter(headline__contains=name)
if categry:
    queryset = queryset.filter(category=categry)
```